# Unable to start server: Gatsby application - Unexpected template string

Tags: javascript, gatsby, mdxjs

I am facing an issue in my gatsby application while trying to start server by npm start/gatsby develop.
The previous time I used, I was not facing any issue, but the next time I tried to start, the error is shown as:

```
Error in "E:\MDX_Blog\mdxBlog\node_modules\gatsby-plugin-mdx\gatsby-node.js": Unexpected template string
```

Attached the screenshot for your reference.
[image: VSCode terminal]

```
    Gatsby config.js

module.exports = {
   plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `posts`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/posts/`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-mdx`,
    `gatsby-plugin-transition-link`,
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`, 
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
  ],
}
```

Comment: Have you installed all packages and dependencies via `npm install`?

Comment: This is not forked from GitHub...my custom development.It was working sterday, I even tested with many browsers but now it's having an issue with MDX plugin.

Answer (score 0):

As the message says, this is a syntax error. A closing `}` is missing.

```
   {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `posts`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/posts/`,
      },
    },
},
```